# How to handle large data sets in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database, nosql

I need help in deciding which schema type is more appropriate for my mongodb collection.

Let's say I want to store a list of things a person have. There will be relatively **small number of people**, but one person can have **very many things**. Let's assume people will be count in **hundreds**, but things a person own in **hundreds of thousands**.

I can think of two options:

**Option 1:**

```
    [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Tom",
        things: [
            {
                name: 'red tie',
                weight: 0.3,
                value: 5
            },
            {
                name: 'carpet',
                weight: 15,
                value: 700
            } //... and 300'000 other things 
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Rob",
        things: [
            {
                name: 'can of olives',
                weight: 0.4,
                value: 2
            },
            {
                name: 'Porsche',
                weight: 1500,
                value: 40000
            }// and 170'000 other things
        ]
    }//and 214 oher people]
]
```

**Option 2:**

> ```
> [
>     {
>         name: 'red tie',
>         weight: 0.3,
>         value: 5,
>         owner: {
>             name: 'Tom',
>             id: 1
>         }
>     },
>     {
>         name: 'carpet',
>         weight: 15,
>         value: 700,
>         owner: {
>             name: 'Tom',
>             id: 1
>         }
>     },
>     {
>         name: 'can of olives',
>         weight: 0.4,
>         value: 2,
>         owner: {
>             name: 'Rob',
>             id: 2
>         }
>     },
>     {
>         name: 'Porsche',
>         weight: 1500,
>         value: 40000,
>         owner: {
>             name: 'Rob',
>             id: 2
>         }
>     }// and 20'000'000 other things
> ];
> ```

1. I will only ask for things **from one owner in a single request** and never ask for things from multiple owners.
2. I will need a **pagination**  for the returned list of things so...
3. ... things will need to be **sorted** by one of the parameters

From what I understand the first point suggest it would be much more efficient to use Option 1 (querying only few hundreds documents instead of millions), but points 2 and 3 are handled much more easily when using Option 2 (limit, skip and sort methods instead of $slice projection and Aggregation Framework).

Can anybody tell me which way would be more suitable? Or maybe I've got something wrong and there's even better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. I will only ask for things from one owner in a single request and never ask for things from multiple owners.
> 2. I will need a pagination for the returned list of things so...
> 3. things will need to be sorted by one of the parameters

Your requirements 2 and 3 would be fulfilled much better by creating a collection where each item is an individual document. With an array, you would have to use the aggregation framework to $unwind that array, which can become quite slow. Your first requirement can easily be optimized for by creating an index on the `owner.name` or `owner.id` field of said collection, depending on which you use for querying.

Also, MongoDB does not handle growing documents very well. To discourage users from creating indefinitely growing documents, MongoDB has a 16MB per document limit. When each of your items is a few hundred byte, hundreds of thousands of array entries would exceed that limit.